# Visual Studio 2010 Not Publishing All Files to File System

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010 is not publishing all files to the file system.  In VS 2008 there was an option to include all files in the project when publishing.  However, VS 2010 does not have this option.  When I go to publish using the file system publish method, certain files are not published such as .pdf files and .flv files.  These files are included in the project so I am not sure why they do not get published.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

VS2010 has an option under

Project -> Package/Publish Settings -> Package/Publish Web (Tab) -> Items to Deploy

Comment: I guess I should have paid attention to that info on the publish dialog.  Thanks!

Comment: while helpful, I don't love that if you pick "All files in the project", it will publish perhaps more than you want (.cs files for example).  I for one like changing the build action to "Content" in Mike Edenfield's answer, more tedious but more exact...

Answer (score 22):

If you specify the items you added to your project as having a build action of "Content" (instead of the default for unknown item types, which I think is "None"), then VS will automatically include it when publishing.

Comment: Good to know. This allows me to keep my documentation files in the project and not deploy them.

Comment: Is there a way to make an extension such as .pdf be included as Content by default?  I'm always having to go back and set new pdfs added to the project as "Content" instead of "None".